# Summing by Column

Tags: obiee

Suppose we have the following columns:

```
       X           Y         Z
    Category     Date      Amount
       A         January   10
       A         February  20
       A         March     30
       B         January   34 
       B         February  45
       B         March     65
       C         January   87
       C         February  98
       C         March     100
       D         January   80
       D         February  90
```

I want to sum the  `Amount`  column by  `Category`  and  `Date` . So for Category A, we would have the sum of the amount be 10+20+30 = 60 for the dates between January and March. In Oracle BI, how would we do this? Note that Some categories might have missing dates. So I want to sum the Amounts for the only the the available dates between January and March. Category D, for example, has March missing. So the total amount would be 80+90 = 170.

When I do the following, I just get the sum of all the amounts:

```
   sum("Z"."Amount")
```

Answer (score 1):

If the required result has to be achieved through OBIEE Answer, then it can be done in following way.
Create a table with columns - Category, Date, Amount.
Go to Results tab. Edit view of the table.

Click on Total By icon above Category column. Both After and Report-Based Total (when applicable) should be ticked.

The result will be coming as shown.

```html
Category   Date      Amount
    A     January     10
          February    20
          March       30
A Total               60
    B     January     34
          February    45
          March       65
B Total               144
    C     January     87
          February    98
          March       100
C Total               285
    D     January     80
          February    90
D Total               170
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite simply by editing the column formula from within the Criteria. When you look at it to begin, your Amount column formula probably looks something like `"Z"."Amount"`. You can edit this slightly to change the aggregation level:

```
sum("Z"."Amount" by "X"."Category")
```

That should give you something like:

```
Category    Date    Amount
A           Jan     60
A           Feb     60
A           Mar     60
B           Jan     144
B           Feb     144
B           Mar     144
```